# GWT url mapping servlet

Tags: java, servlets, gwt

my gwt.xml looks like:

```
<module rename-to="WaitAnalyst">
    [...]
</module>
```

And my web.xml:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>waitstatsServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/databasewatcher/waitstatsservice</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

And my project name is `DatabaseWatcher`

Do you think the first part in the `<url-pattern>` should be `databasewatcher` ot should it be `WaitAnalyst` like the module renaming?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use RPC, the first part should be a module name (i.e. WaitAnalyst).

If you use RequerstBuilder, you can define your own servlet mappings - you can include module name in path or not.